# Building a UseContext Provider typeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

Hi I'm building a UseContext Provider with typescript.
I think I've build it correctly but I've got a litle type error but I can't figure it out.

```html
type SetValue = (value: any) => void;
export interface AppContextInterface {
  value: any;
  setValue: SetValue;
}

export const ExempleCtx = createContext<AppContextInterface | null>(null);

const CtxProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<any>(null);
  return (
    <ExempleCtx.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}>
      {children}
    </ExempleCtx.Provider>
  );
};
export default CtxProvider;
```

```js
interface Test {
  username: any;
}

const defaultState = {
  username: "thomas",
};

export const AppContext = createContext<Test>(defaultState);

export function Hooktest() {
  return (
    <CtxProvider>
      <Btn></Btn>
    </CtxProvider>
  );
}

function Btn() {
  const { value, setValue } = useContext(ExempleCtx);
  return <div onClick={() => setValue("thomas")}>{value}</div>;
}
```

[image]

I tried typing the useState but it's not comming from their. I think its my createContext that is not correctly type.
Thank you for your repplies.

Comment: it have been reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ExempleCtx` has type `AppContextInterface | null` and you cannot destructure from null.

If you are sure, just let TS know that `useContext(ExempleCtx)` will never return null. I think there is no way around it but you have to use type assertion. Use the [`as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) keyword.

```
  const { value, setValue } = useContext(ExempleCtx) as AppContextInterface;
```

If you do not want to fill your codebase with these then just create a seperate hook and return the val with [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator). It tells TS that the value is non-null and non-undefined:

```
const useExempleCtx = () => {
  const val = useContext(ExempleCtx);
  return val!;
};
```

```
  const { value, setValue } = useExempleCtx();
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-hugle-ellvih?file=/src/context/provider.tsx)

Comment: FWIW,  your code shows that the value might be null initially. So i think you should first look at that and fix that part first.

Answer (score 0):

When you first created the context
`export const ExempleCtx = createContext<AppContextInterface | null>(null);`, you set his type to `AppContextInterface | null`. The context *can* be `null`.

To ignore this warning, you can just add a `!` like so 
`const { value, setValue } = useContext(ExempleCtx!);`

Comment: Hi thank you for your repply I tried your solution but I still have the error